# Migration of VB code from 2005 to 2013

Tags: vb.net

we are working on migration project from 2005 to 2013.when we change the version to 4.5, i see few reference dlls have runtime version 1.0,how to resolve that and how can we get the dlls targetted to latest version.I have tried searching in google if i can download the dll's but no luck.

Comment: are you talking about NET assemblies or 3rd party DLLs?

Comment: Both third party and Microsoft dlls